# Why sqlcmd not found during docker-compose up build?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I try to create a docker container of mssql database that is filled up with data when I start it.

I would like to start the database by using the command `docker-compose up --build`

```
docker.yml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  sqlserver:
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:

  mssql:
    container_name: "mssql"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    networks:
      sqlserver:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5

    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "VerySecretP4ssword!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql/backup

COPY backup.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup
COPY restoreScript.sql /var/opt/mssql/backup

RUN sqlcmd -i /var/opt/mssql/backup/restoreScript.sql
```

And after i ran the above mentioned command i get

```
/bin/sh: 1: sqlcmd: not found
ERROR: Service 'mssql' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c sqlcmd -i /var/opt/mssql/backup/restoreScript.sql' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: As a general rule, you can't do this in a Dockerfile.  (What would happen if you deleted and recreated the database container, without rebuilding the image?  What if you update your application code and need to rebuild the image, but don't need to recreate the schema?)  Running a database migration system either as part of your application startup or manually would work better.

Comment: This is just for the development, not for production environment. Basically my aim was to just have a script that creates the database for me with

`docker-compose up --build` and it will be up and running. And later on i can start it or stop it with `docker start/stop mssql`

And also it was important for me to not do any further database creation, but the script does it for me. (Also i don't have much experience with docker)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The return code says, that the command `sqlcmd` was not found in the PATH of your container. In the documentation https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server you can see that `sqlcmd` is in `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/` so modify your RUN command to use the full path.